# Silverstripe - Blog module blog entry via front end but image upload/insert button missing from tinymce

Tags: tinymce, blogs, silverstripe

We allow users to create blog entries via front end. but for some reason the tinymce editor doesn't have image upload button. Authors have to drag the image from their desktop to tinymce to insert an image.

is there a way to add image button allowing authors to upload images and using them in their blog?

Also just realised, there is no "Link" button either

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the default TinyMCE image and link insertion buttons using the code below. However, this won't contain the SilverStripe specific functionality such as choosing a page to link to or uploading images - you have to manually enter link and image URLs.

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get()->addButtonsToLine(1, 'link', 'unlink', 'image');
```

The image and link insertion functionality is quite heavily tied to the CMS in version 2.4, but is being rewritten as part of 3.0 and will work in the front end.

See the [HtmlEditorConfig API documentation](http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/forms/fields-formattedinput/HtmlEditorConfig.html) for more details on customising the functionality available in the WYSIWYG editor.